# React Native Sqlite fetch all data in Listview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using this library: https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage for my react native project.

I retrieve single row from database like this:

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user where id = 1', [], (tx, results) => {
            console.log("Query completed");

            var len = results.rows.length;
           if (len > 0) {
                let row = results.rows.item(0);
                this.setState({userName: row.name});
            }
        });
    });


return (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.userName}</Text>
        </View>
    )
```

But now i want to fetch all data from database, tell me what wrong i am doing in below code:

```
 db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM user', [], (tx, results) => {
            console.log("Query completed");

            var len = results.rows.length;
           for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let row = results.rows.item(i);
                this.setState({record: row.name});
            }
        });
    });




return (
            <View>
                <FlatList data={this.state.record}
                          keyExtractor={(x,i) => 1}
                          renderItem={ ({item}) =>
                              <ListItem><Text>{item.name}</Text></ListItem>
                          }
                />
            </View>
        )
```

can anyone guide me how can i show database data in listview.

Answer (score 1):

Your state value for FlatList data should be an array and you are setting it to a single string every time you itterate through.

Try changing it like below

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ record : prevState.record.push(row.name)}))
```

PS: you need to set your initial state value for `record` as an empty array or so.

Comment: what is prevState?

Comment: Kindly elaborate a bit

Comment: More info can be found in [react's component docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: Any working example for react native sqlite data retrieval in list ?

Comment: bennygenel - can u help me please with sqlite ? i have the insert fetch and delete functions but for some unclear reason it doesn't work .

Answer (score 0):

It works like this

```
record = this.state.record.slice()
                record.push(row.name)
                this.setState({ record: record })
```